# Dictionary keeps getting overwritten in each iteration of for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, dictionary

```
import random

o=['§','±','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','','_','=','+','/','[']
q=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']

for i in top_25:
    wordDic ={i: random.choice(o)+random.choice(q)}
print(wordDic)
```

(top_25 is an array of words, and the random.choice randomly selects characters from the respective arrays). As the for loop iterates, the wordDic keeps updating and overwriting itself-is there a way to add the new values of the wordDic into the dictionary, so it prints out all of them in one dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are defining the dictionary inside the loop.

Which means that you are redifining/overwriting the dictionary during each iteration of the loop ( Comment from: @M.T )

Define it outside the loop to get it work.

```
word_dic = {}
for i in top_25:
    word_dic[i] = random.choice(o)+random.choice(q)
print(word_dic)
```

Comment: worth mentioning to clarify: OP is *re*defining /overwriting the dictionary for every iteration in the loop.

Comment: @M.T: Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

The compact way to do this is with a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays). Also, there's no need to pass `random.choice` a list of single characters: you can just pass it a string.

```
from random import choice

o = u"§±!@#$%^&*()_=+/["
q = u"0123456789"

wordDic = {word: choice(o)+choice(q) for word in top_25}
print(wordDic)
```

I've used the `u` prefix on the strings to make the code compatible to Python 2 as well as Python 3.