# How to stop same combination coming up twice from 2 separate arrays

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
import random
o=['@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','_','=','+','{','}','[',']',';',':','>','<',',','/','|','~','`']
s=['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','_','=','+','{','}','[',']',';',':','?','.','>','<',',','/','|','~','`','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']

twochar = []
for i in a:
     y = random.choice(o)+random.choice(s)
     twochar.append(y)
```

(a is an array containing words). Is there a way to make sure that the same combination, which is picked from the arrays 'o' and 's' doesn't come up more than once in the new array?

Comment: Why are you using a? You are not using 'i' anywhere in the loop.

Comment: I told you [the other day](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36443960/4014959) you can use a string instead of those ugly lists...

Comment: @Akash1993: Presumably the OP wants the resulting list to be the same size as the `a` list.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about ordering, the simplest solution is to use a set:

```
>>> import random
>>> a=10
>>> twochar = set((random.choice(o),random.choice(s)) for i in range(a))
>>> twochar
set([(']', '>'), ('{', '|'), ('$', '&'), ('^', ';'), ('>', '0'), ('@', '2'), ('<', '-'), ('+', '|'), ('%', '^'), ('~', '~')])
```

The use of a `set` means that the result contains only unique items.

...of course, this means that you will potentially have fewer than `a` items, so depending on your needs this may or may not be appropriate.  You can also take advantage of the `set` type for an iterative solution that will keep adding elements to the set until you have the number of elements you want:

```
>>> twochar = set()
>>> while len(twochar) < a:
...   twochar.add((random.choice(o), random.choice(s)))
... 
>>> twochar
set([('@', '9'), ('%', '2'), ('>', '1'), ('~', ';'), ('>', '7'), (':', '~'), ('^', '_'), ('}', '9'), ('^', '>'), ('`', '~')])
```

Comment: In the second example, since `twochar` is a `set`, you don't need to check `if pair not in twochar`. Just add it and loop.

Comment: What @Francesco said: Doing that `if` test is redundant, and it runs at Python speed, whereas the code that `set.add` uses internally runs at C speed.

Answer (score 0):

Just try again if you get a matched pair...

```
for i in a:
    y = '  '
    while y[0] == y[1]:
        y = random.choice(o)+random.choice(s)
    twochar.append(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have been mentioned, the efficient way to do this is to use a set to store your character pairs, since a set cannot contain duplicate items. If you *really* need a list you can easily convert the set to a list, but you may find that your code will work with the set, as is, or can be easily modified to do so, since sets can be iterated over. And if you need to test if certain items are in your `twochar` collection it's **much** faster to test that if `twochar` is a set rather than a list.

As I said in the answer to [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442866/dictionary-keeps-getting-overwritten-in-each-iteration-of-for-loop), there's no need to store the characters as single character strings in a list, `random.choice` will happily select from a string.

Also, it's more efficient to do `from random import choice` rather than `import random` and then call `random.choice` in the list, since using `random.choice` has to look up `.choice` in `random` every time you call it. Alternatively, do `import random` and then do `choice = random.choice` outside the loop, so the resolution is only performed once.

Rather than using a `for` loop we use a `while` loop to ensure that we generate the correct number of pairs.

```
from random import choice

o = '@#$%^&*()_=+{}[];:><,/|~`'
s = '!@#$%^&*()-_=+{}[];:?.><,/|~`1234567890'

a = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'seven', 'words']
alen = len(a)
print(alen)

twochar = set()
while len(twochar) < alen:
    y = choice(o) + choice(s)
    twochar.add(y)

twochar = list(twochar)
print(twochar)
print(len(twochar))
```

**typical output**

```
7
['&&', ';4', ',/', '/#', '<[', '/~', '#]']
7
```